# How to create AWS Cloud HSM using java code

Tags: amazon-web-services, hsm

I am looking for creating aws Cloud HSM using Java sdk.
Does anyone already done? looking for some example.

I can create by using AWS CLI but I want to do it through Java sdk.

Thank you.

Comment: What is missing from the [Java samples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/userguide/java-samples.html)?

Comment: The link is having details about how to communicate to cloud HSM using java. and I am looking for how to create cloud HSM cluster.

Answer (score 1):

AWS CLI is a wrapper around AWS API and the call you are likely looking for is [CreateHSM](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudhsm/latest/APIReference/API_CreateHsm.html) Here is the corresponding [Java SDK method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudhsmv2/AWSCloudHSMV2.html#createHsm-com.amazonaws.services.cloudhsmv2.model.CreateHsmRequest-)

In most cases, if you already know how to do something via CLI - just follow the link to API Reference from the [CLI command documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudhsmv2/create-hsm.html) page and then to SDK of you choice (Java). They all are built on top of the same REST API, so given the example for one it's just a syntax difference on how to work with another.